# What is the best way (Least Read Operations) to do autocomplete on Google App Engine Using Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine

I am currently using ajax to do autocomplete emails and would like to find out what is the best way to do this without too much read operations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do these kind of operations is use the following approach

Use full text search:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/

When creating a document to search on, you could tokenize the email id. for example if you have foobar@baz.com. you could tokenize it to f, fo, foo, foobar .... and save it into a textfield.

then use `index.search` to query for the results.

then every successful lookup can be cached for say 2 hours ( you can change it as per your requirement ).

Anytime you update the model add/update/remove entries then delete the memcache entries/flush the memcache, preferably using the datastore callbacks.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/callbacks

please note that the tokenize + adding a document could to be processed in task queue to fit into the "gae way of doing things"

Also as a footnote, you could try implementing client side caching mechanism using http cache control + etags. I have not implemented such a solution so others could pitch in how their experience was implementing such a solution.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en